# How can I get a day off next week?

Tags: android

How can I get a day off next week from android?

The hour I set for Friday and Sunday is over. I want you to go to friday next week.

This is my code;

```
/**
 * Set Friday Alarm
 */
getNotfDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
getNotfDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, myCustomTime.getHours());
getNotfDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, myCustomTime.getMinutes());
getNotfDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, myCustomTime.getSeconds());

/**
 * 30 minute later from alarm time
 */
getNotfDay.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

/**
 * If Friday time before currently time is set Sunday
 */
if (getNotfDay.getTime().before(Utils.longToDate(System.currentTimeMillis()))) {
    getNotfDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    getNotfDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, myCustomTime2.getHours());
    getNotfDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, myCustomTime2.getMinutes());
}
```

Utils.java

```
public static Date longToDate(long timeMillis){
  return new Date(timeMillis);
}
```

Comment: Hi, it's good that you've got code for us but still unsure on what it is that you are trying to achieve. Do you want to set `getNotfDay` to Friday of next week ?

Comment: When the days I have selected in the current week are over. I want to get next week in Friday and Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add 7 days (1 week).

```
//Set to this week's Friday
getNotfDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
getNotfDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, myCustomTime.getHours());
getNotfDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, myCustomTime.getMinutes());
getNotfDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, myCustomTime.getSeconds());
getNotfDay.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
```